# How to stop automatically open span/Div using selenium web driver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, browser, selenium-webdriver

As per new implementation in my application developer added a "Feedback"(Div/Span) type of box at top right middle of page(near to vertical scroll bar).and below on page has a table which is also in any other div.

I observed that on front End that feedback (Div/Span) overlap over a table(div).

Problem: when i am executing my selenium automation script and perform any operation on table then each time that Feedback (div/Span) type of box open and my table move top left side.so i unable perform any action in top left corner available column in table because they hide due to feedback box open and got an error (element is not visible) ,which is not happen when i am doing manually same process (Manually that Feedback (Div/Span) type box doesn't open when performing any operation in table).
I am executing script in Chrome latest browser.
Please provide me any solution so that feedback type box not open automatically each time and i can perform any operation in table.
Thanks,

Comment: Add your page link and code also

Comment: I can't share details,it's my company policy violation.

Comment: if the feedback type of box open, than close it and perform next operation.

Comment: It's not open but each time performing any action in table it's automatically open and table slide left side and required column elements hide. It's only happen in executing script.

Comment: I got solution: 'element.scrollIntoView(scrollIntoViewOptions); ' after than put fluent wait. It's working for me.